# pandas convert some column values to rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame **df** that looks like this:

[image]

I want them to appear in this format:

[image]

Losing the SignalName column. I need it in this format because I have to plot time vs SDLxvalues. I think it requires some kind of iterator, I have tried melt but didn't work.

Comment: don't post images. Please copy and paste it in form of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.set_index(['time','SignalName'])['value'].unstack()
```

Output:

```
SignalName  APID1  SLID1  SPID1
time                           
t_1             1      0      2
t_2            11      0     22
t_3             1      0     20
```

Another option:

```
df_out = df.set_index(['time','SignalName']).unstack()
df_out.columns = [f'{j}{i}' for i, j in df_out.columns]
df_out.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  time  APID1value  SLID1value  SPID1value
0  t_1           1           0           2
1  t_2          11           0          22
2  t_3           1           0          20
```

Duplicate values, you need to aggregate time some how, here I am choosing the first value, you can do sum, mean, max, min or any aggregation of your choice.

```
df.groupby(['time', 'SignalName'])['value'].agg('first').unstack()
```

Output:

```
SignalName  APID1  SLID1  SPID1
time                           
t_1             1      0      2
t_2            11      0     22
t_3             1      0     20
```

Comment: I am getting error Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape . I have NaNs in the entire dataset I think I had to ention that.

Comment: Thanks, I just had to save the time index into a list and sort it actually my dataset has upto t_1200 for every sequence.